# Webscraping page_soup.findAll i need to extract especific data from a webpage but dont know how to do it

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am trying to do some webscraping and i need to extract the keywords from a webpage. I am trying to use page_soup.findAll() to extract it but i dont know what to insert between () to extract what i need.

The code of the page is the following:

```
var kv = {"seccion": "otros","nivel": "home","nota": "","id_nota": "","tipo": "noticias","keywords" : "IMPUESTOS,  SII,  EXCEDENTES ISAPRES,  INCENDIOS,  COLUSION CONFORT,  COMPENSACION,  PERMISOS DE CIRCULACION,  REVISION TECNICA"};
```

And i need these data:

"IMPUESTOS,  SII,  EXCEDENTES ISAPRES,  INCENDIOS,  COLUSION CONFORT,  COMPENSACION,  PERMISOS DE CIRCULACION,  REVISION TECNICA"

Thanks

Comment: this code is not HTML but JavaScript - so `findaAll()` is useless for this. You have it as string so use string functions to get it - ie. slicing `[start:end]`, `split()`, `replace()`, etc.  OR you can remove from this string `var kv = ` and `;` and you will have JSON string which you can convert to Python's dictionary using module `json` and then you can get it from dictionary - `dictionary["keywords"]`

Answer (score 0):

This is not `HTML` but `JavaScript` so `findaAll()` is useless for this.

You have it as string so use string functions to get it - ie. slicing `[start:end]`, `split()`, `replace()`, etc.

OR you can remove from this string `var kv =` and `;` and you will have JSON string which you can convert to Python's dictionary using module `json` and then you can get it from dictionary - `dictionary["keywords"]`

```
text = 'var kv = {"seccion": "otros","nivel": "home","nota": "","id_nota": "","tipo": "noticias","keywords" : "IMPUESTOS,  SII,  EXCEDENTES ISAPRES,  INCENDIOS,  COLUSION CONFORT,  COMPENSACION,  PERMISOS DE CIRCULACION,  REVISION TECNICA"};'

text = text[9:-1]  # remove `var kv = ` and `;`

import json

d = json.loads(text)

print(d['keywords'])
```